# jQuery: ajax() / jsonp: cross browser

Tags: jquery

I have a cross-browser form that is called in an iframe. The form has 'dynamic' select menus. I am using the jQuery `getJSON()` function to query the data. I have been unable to successfully update the `select` menu with the following code, it seems like it should work wikiPresto. The data is returning (i can see it in firebug) but the `select` is not updating...

Any thoughts on what i am doing wrong?

note: #foo and #bar are select menus...

```
var $f = $('#foo');
var $b = $('#bar');
$b.change(function() {
    var foo = $f.val();
    var bar = $b.val();
    $.getJSON("http://example.com/form.php", {f: foo, b: bar},
        function(foo){
            varbar = $('#foo');
            varbar.html(foo.data);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this page is not also on `http://example.com`, then you need to use JSONP.

Add `?callback=?` to the url, to make jQuery use JSONP.

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/form.php?callback=?", {f: foo, b: bar},
  function(foo){
  }
);
```

form.php will have to wrap the JSON in the value of `$_GET['callback']`.  The data returned from form.php should look like this:

```
callback({data: 'test'});
```

[Wikipedia article on JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: +1, this answer could be improved with a link to a `JSONP` explanation though. :)

Comment: @Alex: I added a link to the Wikipedia article :-)